How to insert an ObjectId into a document in mongo and golang
I'm having a problem inserting an ObjectId into a doc.
this is the collection sale model
type Sale struct {
    ID      primitive.ObjectID   `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Client  primitive.ObjectID   `bson:"client"`
    Items   []primitive.ObjectID `bson:"items"`
    Amounts []int                `bson:"amounts"`
    Cost    float64              `bson:"cost"`
    Payment bool                 `bson:"payment"`
    Date    time.Time            `bson:"date"`
}

before generating the insert I ensured that Sale.Client has a valid ObjectId value, but when I perform this insert the value becomes binary within the table.
ex:
ObjectId('67103588b9138d78d5ef09a2')
Binary.createFromBase64('ZxA1iLkTjXjV7wmi', 0)
this is the insert code
func CommonInsert(collection string, ctx context.Context, model interface{}) error {
    conn, err := config.GetDbConnection(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    c := conn.Database("teste").Collection(collection)

    _, err = c.InsertOne(ctx, model)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

I generated real mock data for the insert and I still couldn't force the data to be transformed into ObjectId

Are you by any chance using multiple versions of the library? There's a beta v2.0, but you sould use the v1 everywhere (or beta v2 everywhere). Show a [mcve].

That was exactly the problem, it's using v2 in some parts of the driver and not in others, thank you very much!!!

Usually when a primitive.ObjectID is not being recognized as a MongoDB ObjectId type (but rather an ordinary byte array which is the underlying type of primitive.ObjectID), it boils down to:

either you actually using a custom type (having primitive.ObjectID as its underlying type) such as type MyID primitive.ObjectID instead of primitive.ObjectID exactly
or you mixing major driver versions

Currently there is a beta v2 major version of the driver, and there is of course the v1. Make sure you don't mix the 2 major versions: either use v1 or beta v2 everywhere.

Assuming that this is a schema to which we would like to map our data to be persisted in our MongoDB collection, I tend to invoke primitive.NewObjectID(), which will generate an instance of primitive.ObjectID, which now shall be assigned to the field ID.
type User struct {
  Id  primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
}
    

user1 := User{
    Id: primitive.NewObjectID()
}

persisting the data into MongoDB collection, invoke the Mongo collection that you would like to insert your data into, in this case
users_col.InsertOne(ctx, user1)

